# LAPS (local administrator password) command

Tags: active-directory, powershell, shell-scripting

Anyone knows if this is possible to change LAPS command so it sets permissions 1 user to 1 computer? The reason is I want to allow target user to be able to view his computer laps password. Currently,

```
Set-AdmPwdReadPasswordPermission -OrgUnit OU -AllowedPrincipals UsersAndGroups
```

command sets permissions for a user to read  `ms-Mcs-AdmPwd` attribute on AD. But the issue is that a user is able to read another computer's `ms-Mcs-AdmPwd` attribute in same OU as well.

Comment: Why not just grant the user access to read the extended attributes on that one computer object? You don't need a cmdlet for this.